# Use Dictionaries for HP to my Enemies

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I´m building a tower defense game.I need to get "enemies" with 2 Health.

I've been trying:

```
foreach (float enemyKey in enemyKeysAAB)
{
    if (bullets[key].Intersects(enemyHitboxAAB[enemyKey]))
    {
        if (hpLEnemyAAB.Contains(enemyKey))
        {
            money += 20;
            tScore += 155;
            removeLEnemyAAB.Add(enemyKey);
            hpLEnemyAAB.Remove(enemyKey);
        }
        else if (bullets[key].Intersects(enemyHitboxAAB[enemyKey]))
        {
            removebullet.Add(key);
            hpLEnemyAAB.Add(enemyKey);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using dictionaries to spawn and etc so [enemykey] in my code are each and every enemy.

I´m writing this in Game.cs cause we are not allowed to use classes and I don't know how to use one.

How can i use dictionaries to make enemies with HP?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear...Also you don't have to put XNA in the title. It has nothing to do with Xna. Also even if it did have anything to do with xna, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `enemyHP<float, int>` dictionary I guess. where `enemyHP[enemyKey]` would give you that enemy's HP. And then you just check:

```
if (--enemyHP[enemyKey] < 1)
{
    // Dead
}
```